# Why is It happining this error when I run the app?

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app on that the idea is click on the button and changing an image. every time I click on the button an imageview change (dynamic imageview). I'm trying to do that but when I run the code below the first imageview is loaded and when I press the button, the first imageview jump to last imageview, ignoring two imageviews among them. What's wrong?

This is my code:

```
 SEGUNDATELA. JAVA:

       public class SegundaTela extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Integer [] imagens = new Integer[]{R.drawable.tabeladia2, R.drawable.tabeladia3, R.drawable.tabeladia4, R.drawable.tabeladia5};
        private RadioGroup radioGroup;
        private RadioButton sim;
        private RadioButton nao;
        private Button proxima;
        private ImageView img;
        private int i=0;
        private Integer [] dados= new Integer[4];
        private int soma =0;
        private int j;
        private int inicio;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda_tela);

            img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            proxima = findViewById(R.id.proximaId);
            radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.RadioGroupId);
            sim = findViewById(R.id.simId);
            nao = findViewById(R.id.naoId);

            if (sim.isChecked()) {
                inicio = 1;
            } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                inicio = 0;
            }


            proxima.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (i < 4) {
                        ++i;
                        j = (i - 1);

                        switch (j) {

                            case 0:

                                if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[j]);
                                    dados[j] = 2;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[j]);
                                    dados[j] = 0;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:

                                if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[j]);
                                    dados[j] = 4;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[j]);
                                    dados[j] = 0;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:

                                if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[j]);
                                    dados[j] = 8;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[j]);
                                    dados[j] = 0;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:

                                if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[j]);
                                    dados[j] = 16;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[j]);
                                    dados[j] = 0;
                                }
                                break;

                        }
                        radioGroup.clearCheck();

                    } else {
                        soma = dados[0] + dados[1] + dados[2] + dados[3] + inicio;
                        Intent i = new Intent(SegundaTela.this, MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("soma", soma);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }


            });

        }
        }

SEGUNDATELA.MML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/proximaId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="proxima"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tabeladia1" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RadioGroupId"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/simId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sim" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/naoId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Não" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although you question got answered fast, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when you have the time, so it will be easier for us to help in you next questions. Also avoid code in another languages, it's not a really big problem, but if everything is in english it's even easier for the community to help you. There's also a [Stack Overflow in portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) where you can get help. (Though I prefer here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the for loop and increment everytime the button is clicked.

Use this if you want the images to be shown in a loop.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int [] imagens = {R.drawable.tabeladia2, R.drawable.tabeladia3,
            R.drawable.tabeladia4, R.drawable.tabeladia5};

    private Button proxima;
    private ImageView img;
    private Integer currentImg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        proxima = findViewById(R.id.proximaId);

        img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        proxima.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentImg != null && currentImg < 3) {
                    currentImg++;
                } else {
                    currentImg = 0;
                }
                img.setImageResource(imagens[currentImg]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Use this if you don't want the images to be looped

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            private int [] imagens = {R.drawable.tabeladia2, R.drawable.tabeladia3,
                    R.drawable.tabeladia4, R.drawable.tabeladia5};

            private Button proxima;
            private ImageView img;
            private Integer currentImg;

            private int[] intArray = new int[4];

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                proxima = findViewById(R.id.proximaId);

                img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                proxima.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (currentImg != null) {
                            if (currentImg < 3) {
                                currentImg++;
                                if(currentImg == 1){
                                  intArray[1] = 2;
                                }else if(currentImg == 2){
                                  intArray[2] = 4;
                                }else if(currentImg == 3){
                                  intArray[3] = 8;}
                                img.setImageResource(imagens[currentImg]);
                            }else{
                                //handle last image reached condition
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Last image reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            currentImg = 0;
                            intArray[0] = 1;
                            img.setImageResource(imagens[currentImg]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Using Case Statement and RadioButtons.

```
public class SegundaTela extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Integer[] imagens = new Integer[]{R.drawable.tabeladia2, R.drawable.tabeladia3, R.drawable.tabeladia4, R.drawable.tabeladia5};
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton sim;
    private RadioButton nao;
    private Button proxima;
    private ImageView img;
    private Integer i;
    private int soma = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda_tela);

        img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        proxima = findViewById(R.id.proximaId);
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.RadioGroupId);
        sim = findViewById(R.id.simId);
        nao = findViewById(R.id.naoId);


        proxima.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!sim.isChecked() && !nao.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SegundaTela.this, "Select an option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (i != null) {
                    if (i < 5) {
                        switch (i) {
                            case 0:

                                if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
                                    //dados[j] = 2;
                                    soma = soma + 2;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
                                    //dados[j] = 0;
                                    soma = soma + 0;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:

                                if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
                                    //dados[j] = 4;
                                    soma = soma + 4;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
                                    //dados[j] = 0;
                                    soma = soma + 0;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:

                                if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
                                    //dados[j] = 8;
                                    soma = soma + 8;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
                                    //dados[j] = 0;
                                    soma = soma + 0;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:

                                if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
                                    //dados[j] = 16;
                                    soma = soma + 16;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    img.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
                                    //dados[j] = 0;
                                    soma = soma + 0;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                /*if (sim.isChecked()) {
                                    //dados[j] = 16;
                                    soma = soma + 32;

                                } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                                    //dados[j] = 0;
                                    soma = soma + 0;
                                }*/
                                Intent i = new Intent(SegundaTela.this, MainActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("soma", soma);
                                startActivity(i);
                                break;
                        }
                        ++i;
                        Toast.makeText(SegundaTela.this, "soma: " + soma, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        radioGroup.clearCheck();

                    } /*else {
                        //soma = dados[0] + dados[1] + dados[2] + dados[3] + inicio;
                        Intent i = new Intent(SegundaTela.this, MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("soma", soma);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }*/
                }else {
                    if (sim.isChecked()) {
                        //inicio = 1;
                        soma = soma + 1;
                    } else if (nao.isChecked()) {
                        //inicio = 0;
                        soma = soma + 0;
                    }
                    i = 0;
                    radioGroup.clearCheck();
                }
            }


        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked. I'd like to add a change of activity after the last image as well. But every time I put startActivity(new Intent(...)) jump to second screen when I click the button in the first time.

Comment: @PauloAndrade You can use the second solution for that. Remove the "Last image reached" toast and add `startActivity()` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I did that and It worked. i'd like to store values now. For example: every time an imageview is shown, it stores an value "int " into array, in other words, every  value of "currentImg" will store an value "int". currentImage = 0 ->1, currentImg=1 ->2, currentImg =2 ->4, etc. How could I do that? I tried but It's given error.

Comment: Oh ok I got it Aruan!! So it means I need to check every currentImg alone. That's why I was making mistakes. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Thank you so much. I did using swtich... case, on that a  "currentImage" will increment and treated in every case. I'm trying to do a sum of values  of "intArray": intArray[0] + intArray[1]+...with two radiobuttons "yes" and "no" but the sum is wrong. I can't understand.

Comment: @PauloAndrade Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: Ok. Arun. I updated the code above!!! Thank you. As I said, there are two radiobuttons to each imageview. These radiobuttons are updated every time I click on the button "proxima", in other words, they clear and store every value in array and in the end, these values of array are sumed. the result of sum is wrong. NOTE: I've already changed in AndroidManifest the priority of activities to test. That's why Second screen open Main Activity. I wonder If It doesn't work to do  If... else with array elements.

Comment: @PauloAndrade I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. Can you post your xml files with radio buttons too? From what i understand the value for `soma` is wrong currently?

Comment: That's right friend. I have a single activity with one radiogrupoup ( two radiobuttons), one button and five imageviews. I dicided to do all of inside just one activity. When I click the button, it update the imageview, clear radiogroup (reuse the radiobuttons), doing this loop for three times. the radiobutton "sim" store the values above and radiobutton "não" store zero. In the end the value stored in every array element is sumed, but the result of sum is wrong and I don't know beacuse that. I updated the code putting my .xml. Thank you.

Comment: @PauloAndrade I have updated my answer. I have moved the intent to case 4 incase you want to add some value for that also.

Answer (score 1):

Ever time you execute onClick() the entire for loop will execute. That is why. If you only want it to proceed one image at the time you need to find a different solution that allows you to keep state (knowing current image) between the "clicks".

Comment: How Can I do that?

Comment: In many different ways, try something. But you will need to save the index outside the method as a class variable.